# JSON parse instruction in PHP

Tags: php, json

I need some help to parse JSON in PHP.

The JSON below is in the variable $response

```
[
  {
    "id": "6b3c7ccf7291170020b657aa06b6cfd3",
    "app": "passbook",
    "os": "ios",
    "registered": "2017-01-10T01:19:27Z",
    "pushToken": "bf32dc858e02bddbbd21df9e95b094e5b0edb6cf0ebd8b6c757799866c3ce5e3",
    "lastSeen": "2017-04-19T21:07:03Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "9ac290d5186a081c5498c604db9f8d59",
    "app": "passbook",
    "os": "ios",
    "registered": "2017-02-16T16:15:02Z",
    "pushToken": "702c5f8077bda33d2cbafbcabba78b230668877ef08abbff5420017be221700d",
    "lastSeen": "2017-02-16T16:15:02Z"
  }
]
```

I need to get the id and app detail from both and display it.

The code I have is

```
$json = json_decode($response,true);


foreach ($json as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['app'];
}
```

I am getting the error

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: And what issue are you getting?

Comment: I am getting this error PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: The above code will work to parse the JSON and get the id and app details. what issue you are facing?

Comment: above JSON is valid. Please print the $json array. If the JSON is decoded, you can overcome this issue

Comment: I tested it on postman and that is the JSON i am getting. That is what is confusing me.

Comment: check this. its working. https://eval.in/784129

Comment: I looked over and the curl that generated the JSON had an error in it. Thank you everyone. I really thought I was going insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working fine for me.

Possible reason why not working for you:-

1.May be your `json` variable is something else rather than `$response`.

2.`$resonse` have more data and that data may have some problem (show us full data in that case).

3.Maybe some other code before `$json = json_decode($response,true);` is there whcih is dealing with `$response`already.

Please check below:-

```
<?php

$response = '[
  {
    "id": "6b3c7ccf7291170020b657aa06b6cfd3",
    "app": "passbook",
    "os": "ios",
    "registered": "2017-01-10T01:19:27Z",
    "pushToken": "bf32dc858e02bddbbd21df9e95b094e5b0edb6cf0ebd8b6c757799866c3ce5e3",
    "lastSeen": "2017-04-19T21:07:03Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "9ac290d5186a081c5498c604db9f8d59",
    "app": "passbook",
    "os": "ios",
    "registered": "2017-02-16T16:15:02Z",
    "pushToken": "702c5f8077bda33d2cbafbcabba78b230668877ef08abbff5420017be221700d",
    "lastSeen": "2017-02-16T16:15:02Z"
  }
]';

$json = json_decode($response,true);

echo "<pre/>";print_r($json);

foreach ($json as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $row['app'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/784126